# How can I show that the arguments that minimize a function are not affected by a constant (or not affected much by a constant)?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, problem-solving

Edit: I feel this question is better suited for MathOverflow, so I added a significant amount of context and posted there. I don't know if I should delete the question on this site, but I feel I should provide the link to not duplicate work. Here is the link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375682/how-can-i-analyze-the-the-affect-of-a-constant-on-the-arguments-that-minimize-a

Consider the a function $f(x,y,c)$ where $c$ is a constant. I just wrote $c$ as an argument to emphasize the function contains an important parameter $c$. Now, consider

$$\text{argmin}_{x,y} \; f(x,y,c)$$

**How can I either (1) show that the arguments that minimize $f$ is not affected by the choice of $c$, or furthermore, (2) how can I determine how much the parameter $c$ affects the arguments that minimize $f$. I am mostly interested in (2), but I am convinced I need to understand (1) to work out (2).**

While the problems I am typically working with are not so simple, I will provide a simple example to illustrate my question.

Example 1: Consider
$$ f(x,y,c) = cx^2 + y^2 $$
where $c > 0$. The minimum of this function is $x=0$ and $y=0$ regardless of the value of $c$. This is simple to see for this function.

Example 2: Consider the following equations,
$$ f_1(x,y,c) = (x+c*0.00001)^2 + y^2 $$
$$ f_2(x,y,c) = (x+c)^2 + y^2 $$

The value of $c$ in the first equation $f_1$ does not affect the minimizing arguments as much as the value of $c$ in the second equation $f_2$.

Comment: Did you consider the behavior of $$f(x,y,c) = x^{(c^y)}+x^{(c^{-y})}$$ in particular fpr $c < 1$ and $c > 1$?

Comment: @vvgiri I don't understand the relationship between the equation you provide and my question. Why do you suggest looking at the behavior?

Comment: Even in the example $f(x,y,c) = cx^2 + y^2$, when the value of $c$ is negative, say $c = -1$ versus $c = +1$, the $(x,y)$ vary depending on the choice of $c$ doesn't it. In fact, when $c$ is negative, there is no global minima. Same for the equation I gave (it doesn't have a minima). So, when the choice of $c$ influences whether the function even has a global minima exists or not, how can we make a statement that the choice of $c$ does not impact the minima of $f$?

Comment: @vvg I see. Thanks. I made a mistake when creating the example as I meant the first example to not be affected by $c$. The purpose is to help illustrate my question. Even so, is there a systematic way for showing if $c$ does not impact the minima of $f$? If this function was more complicated, perhaps the impact would not be obvious by inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is sourced from Oregon State University Calculus Undergraduate Study Guide.*
[See **References**]

Compute $f'_x(x,y,c)$ and $f'_y(x,y,c)$ the partial derivatives of $f(x,y,c)$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Equate the partial derivatives to $0$ and solve them simultaneously to determine critical points (i.e., maxima or minima) where the tangent plane is horizontal with its normal pointing in the $z$ direction.

Let $(x_c,y_c)$ be a critical point on the 2D surface given by $f(x,y,c)$.

Define $D(x_c,y_c) = f''_x(x,y,c)f''_y(x,y,c) - [f''_{xy}(x_c, y_c, c)]^2$

where

$f''_x(x,y,c)$ and $f''_y(x,y,c)$ are the second derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$ respectively and

$f''_{xy}(x,y,c)$ is the second derivative of $f(x,y,c)$ w.r.t $x$ first followed by $y$ next.

We have four cases:

- If $D>0$ and $f_xx(x_c,y_c)<0$, then $f(x,y)$ has a relative maximum
  at $(x_c,y_c)$.
- If $D>0$ and $f_xx(x_c,y_c)>0$, then $f(x,y)$ has a relative minimum
  at $(x_c,y_c)$.
- If $D<0$, then $f(x,y)$ has a saddle point at $(x_c,y_c)$.
- If $D=0$, the second derivative test is inconclusive.

From this we can see that for the question posed, if $c$ appears in the partial derivatives $f'_x(x,y,c)$ or $f'_y(x,y,c)$ we can conclude that it impacts the maxima or minima for general $f(x,y,c)$. The extent of the impact is defined exactly by the system of two equations that equate the partial derivatives to $0$ in the computation of the critical points.

**References:**

[Maxima and Minima of Functions of Two Variables](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html). Oregon State University, Calculus study guide.